# How can I update all entries of a dictionary in Python with certain logic?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I have a dictionary with key value pairs of a persons name with a list of domain names like so

```
dictionary = {
'Trent':['help.google.com', 'smooth.google.com', 'bob.google.com'],
'Bill':['help.google.com', 'smooth.google.com', 'bob.google.com', 'trent.awesome.net']}
```

I want to make it so that in the dictionary, there is only the parent domain (instead of smooth.google.com it's just google.com). Ordinarily, with a regular list I'll use code like this get the parent domain names:

```
domains = ['help.google.com', 'smooth.google.com', 'bob.google.com', 'trent.awesome.net']
parents = []
for domain in domains:
    parents.append(domain[domain.index('.') + 1:])
```

Now I'm trying to combine that logic with logic that makes sure that in the dictionary, among values no matter the key, there are no duplicates using Counter and list comprehension. That code is this:

```
cnt = Counter()
for idx in result.values():
    cnt.update(idx)
res = {idx: [key for key in j if cnt[key] == 1]
               for idx, j in result.items()}
```

When I try to combine the logic, the BEST I'll get is an empty list next to the name. Using the above example of a dictionary the result will be

```
'Trent':[]
```

I tried using two for loops like so:

```
cnt = Counter()
for idx in result.values():
    for x in idx:
        x = x[x.index('.') + 1:]
        cnt.update(idx)
res = {idx: [key for key in j if cnt[key] == 1]
               for idx, j in result.items()}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I hope I've provided sufficient detail in my question.

Comment: If you're looking for only the parent domains, one thing I'm noticing right away is that the parent domain name is added as the second to last string in the dot-separated list. Maybe use `split('.')` and iterate in reverse order to find similarities?

Answer (score 1):

This script will filter out domains in the list and keeps only parent domains:

```
dictionary = {
'Trent':['help.google.com', 'smooth.google.com', 'bob.google.com'],
'Bill':['help.google.com', 'smooth.google.com', 'bob.google.com', 'trent.awesome.net']}

out = {k: [*set(vv.split('.', maxsplit=1)[-1] for vv in v)] for k, v in dictionary.items()}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'Trent': ['google.com'], 'Bill': ['google.com', 'awesome.net']}
```

---

EDIT: To filter out the duplicities across every key, you can use this:

```
out, seen = {}, set()
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    for vv in v:
        domain = vv.split('.', maxsplit=1)[-1]
        if domain not in seen:
            out.setdefault(k, []).append(domain)
            seen.add(domain)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'Trent': ['google.com'], 'Bill': ['awesome.net']}
```

Comment: This is so close but is it possible to modify this so it would the second key value pair would not contain google.com?

Comment: You're a godsend! Thank you!